# Delete pdf files in a folder using a batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, command, dos

I would like to run a batch (.bat containing DOS commands) that would clean my folder by deleting any pdf that is still there. How do you do that ?

Comment: Just so you know, we like to see people do a good web search for their question before asking here - I'd expect this question will have been answered many times on the internet already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
del *.pdf /q
```

Explanation:

```
del   -- Dos command to delete files

*.pdf -- all files with the .PDF extension in the current directory

/q    -- Don't ask for confirmation.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming only one directory (no sub-directories):
del *.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, that exactly answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

http://ss64.com/nt/

Use /q and DEL commands.